# Export Excel to XML with added string

Tags: xml, excel, export-to-xml, vba

I have an Excel file that contains the column persons. In order to export this Excel sheet to XML I provided an XML schema that looks like this:

```
<members>
    <person></person>
</members>
```

If I export it to XML afterwards the XML looks like the following:

```
<members>
    <person>Bob</person>
</members>
```

Since since Bob is the only one in my table persons it means that everything worked. However I want the XML to look like this:

```
<members>
    <person><![CDATA[Bob]]></person>
</members>
```

I could adjust the output myself by running a macro before the export but I'm looking for a way to make the output XML look like that automatically. How can I archieve that? Thanks.

Comment: YOu will either have to create that macro or write the XML from a macro entirely. Excel's export to XML is very limited.

Comment: I gotta ask, why would you store your data in a CDATA (making it much harder to use in all other XML processing)?